# Initialize object with parameter by DI in asp core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I have common DI usage in asp core application.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddScoped(typeof(IUnitOfWork), typeof(UnitOfWork));//DAL
    services.AddScoped(typeof(IUpService), typeof(UpService));//BLL
    ...
}
```

Controller get UpService by DI:

```
public BaseController(IUpService upService)
{
    _upService = upService;
}
```

And in its turn BLL (upservice) get unitofwork instance:

```
public UpService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
{
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
}
```

In base controller i have property CurrentUser

```
public User CurrentUser
{
    get
    {
        User user = null;
        var tokenCookie = HttpContext.Request.Headers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Key == "token");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenCookie.Value) && tokenCookie.Value != "undefined")
        {
            user = _upService.GetUserById(new Guid(tokenCookie.Value));
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

What i need is to pass `CurrentUser` to BL layer (to `UpService`). How to realise it by DI in asp core?

UPD:
Here the part of UpService, where i need  current user.

```
public class UpService : IUpService
{
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public User CurrentUser { get; set; }


    public UpService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IUserContext userContext)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        //CurrentUser = userContext.CurrentUser;
    }


    public void Update(Document doc)
        {
//here complex BL and then...
                Document local;
                var entity = _unitOfWork.DocumentsRepository.GetByID(doc.Id);
                if (entity != null && HasChanges(local, entity))
                {
                    entity.ChangedById = CurrentUser.Id;
                    _unitOfWork.Save();
                }
        }

        public User GetUserById(Guid id)
        {
            return _unitOfWork.UserRepository.GetByID(id);
        }
```

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extract the `CurrentUser` into an abstraction, let's call it `IUserContext`. This abstraction can be implemented in your core layer. This way BL and DAL can access it. As part of your web application you create an implementation that adapts to ASP.NET Core and basically contains the logic that your `CurrentUser` property has. For instance:

```cs
public interface IUserContext
{
    User CurrentUser { get; }
}
```

The adapter can look as follows:

```cs
public class AspNetUserContextAdapter : IUserContext
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
    private readonly IUpService _upService;

    public AspNetUserContextAdapter(IHttpContextAccessor accessor, IUpService _upService) { 
        _accessor = accessor;
        _upService = upService;
    }

    public User CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            var context = _accessor.HttpContext;
            var tokenCookie = context.Request.Headers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Key == "token");
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenCookie.Value) && tokenCookie.Value != "undefined"
                ? _upService.GetUserById(new Guid(tokenCookie.Value))
                :  null;
        }
    }
}
```

This adapter can be registered as usual:

```cs
services.AddTransient<IUserContext, AspNetUserContextAdapter>();
```

On top of that, you might need to register ASP.NET Core's `IHttpContextAccessor`, since (in old versions of ASP.NET Core) it is not registered by default:

```cs
services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Comment: Steven, thanks for your response. It seems that i need. But after realisation if found "circular dependency". In fact i ask IUserContext in IUpService. And in result IUserContext needs IUpService, but IUpservice needs IUserContext. And how to solve it?

Comment: @VitalyMosin: Please update your question and show the implementation of `UpService`. Typically though, circular references are caused by Single Responsibility Principle violations; in other words, `UpService` is probably too big and should be split.

Comment: I agree that may be i violate RSP. May be the solution is to cut service injection for userContext and pass to upservice just a token. Then i could get User in upservice constructor and return it to controller by _upService.CurrentUser property

Comment: @VitalyMosin: Can you do another update? You don't show the part of `UpService` that uses the `CurrentUser`.

Comment: @VitalyMosin: The solution is simple. Segregate `GetUserById` and `Update` by giving them their own interface and implementation. This ensures that you play by the rules of SOLID. Also take a look at [this article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) and [this](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) to get inspiration of how to design SOLID code.

Comment: Do note however that the setting of the `ChangedById` property is an infrastructural concern; in your design, you will see this duplicated through the complete business layer. It might be good to extract this out of the BL and move this to the ORM tool. If you use EF for instance, you can hook onto its events to ensure changed entities are updated with the current user just before saving.